# Absolute positioning the child inside of parent with padding

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a carrier element (aka parent) that contains another div as a child.
The parent has a padding.

I need to vertically position the child using `absolute` however I've noticed that this messes up the width of the child, which should be 100% (filling the entire width of the parent, obeying the margins).

Here is an example codepen link:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKzwb

**P.S. I'm looking for a solution that'll work in a dynamic way, instead of setting each possible child content's left or right values manually.**

I'm pretty sure there was easy solution of this; would love to remember -

Comment: Please post the code you're using.

Comment: just posted it as a link

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: @mark I'm looking for a no-js solution. I know it's doable with js.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure if it's the best solution, but the result expected is here :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjgmh

changes made :

```
left: 64px;
right: 64px;
width: auto;
```

take also consideration of Sean Jermey answer by putting relative value of the parent.

Edit: To make only one "dynamic way" i propose this css selector :

```
#parent > .child {
//each generalize child behavior
}
```

Comment: This is not the type of solution I'm looking for. I'm looking for a more generalized solution, instead of setting each child element one by one.

Comment: can you tell us everything you need please, because the implication of mutiple child elements was not involved, help us find the best solution for you.

Comment: btw, if you have multiple child, you can simply change id to class to all of them. That way, all child will have the same behavior.

Comment: I'm of course looking for a solution that'll fit the "margins" issue I stated in the problem. Multiple child elements are not necessarily the same class. Shortly, the solution should be simple, that's the main reason I have a padding in the carrier in the first place. Otherwise what's the meaning of all this?

Comment: as I stated I don't find this solution to be interesting or generalized.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use a relative parent and change padding to margin:

```
position: relative;
margin: 64px; /* absolute is ignoring the padding attribrute */
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/o73pb7j4/

But as you criticised with the other answers, a dynamic solution for multiple children will be hard to accomplish while using absolute positing as each child will absolute position from the top of the parent. If this isn't related to your question then please elaborate as I have misunderstood what you're looking for.

This link may be of more help:

http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/css/css-absolute-position-taking-into-account-padding.html

Comment: How is this anyhow related to what I'm looking for?